# createin testcases via karma-jasmine in angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am kinds of stuck. Here is what we are doing. 
We have written angular code in 2.0 style where our app.js ahs the magic to convert components in directive and controller which is little complex.
 Now I have to write test cases using karma & jasmine and we have create a framework for that but it doesn't work if I call our angular code. If I remove app.js from the angular code then I can reach to the class function, but as I add our app.js it give me errors like

Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
even though the kquery is already loaded.

or 
22 10 2015 14:31:34.895:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /app/vendor/angular/angular-aria.js
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

But if I write a small class/component everything works fine.

Has anyone did this(coding in 2.0 style) and written test cases for that.
If yes can you please help me what I should be doing or not doing.
Thank you
Manish